# How to dynamically set Background color for InkPresenter

Tags: windows-phone-7

I added an InkPresenter in XAML. How to I dynamically change its background colour?

Is this workable?

```
 ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();           


ib.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;

 ib.ImageSource = 
new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/WhiteBoard_1000.jpg", UriKind.Relative));

 myInk.Background = ib;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the background of the InkPresenter just as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

You can change InkPresenter background in XAML, but changing its background Dynamically, use this:

SolideColorBrush sb = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Color_you_want);

InkPresenter.background = sb;